# Orchard CMS - Related posts widget

Tags: orchardcms

I need a "related-posts" widget for my orchard site, but I couldn't found it in Modules Gallery. Are there any tutorial for this sort of issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good series here:

http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2011/06/real-world-orchard-cmspart-7finding.html

The article linked explains how to do related articles based on tags.

Answer (score 0):

Does this also help? http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.I9AOrchard.LinksRelacionados